# Thread.Sleep() usage to Prevent Server Overload

Tags: c#, multithreading

I wrote some code that mass imports a high volume of users into AD. To refrain from overloading the server, I put a thread.sleep() in the code, executed at every iteration.

Is this a good use of the method, or is there a better alternative (.NET 4.0 applies here)?

Does Thread.Sleep() even aid in performance? What is the cost and performance impact of sleeping a thread?

Comment: What leads you to believe that it's possible to overload the server?

Comment: What exactly is "a high volume" in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Thread.Sleep is one way to handle this; @cHao is correct that using a timer would allow you to do this in another fashion. Essentially, you're trying to cut down number of commands sent to the AD server over a period of time.

In using timers, you're going to need to devise a way to detect trouble (that's more intuitive than a try/catch).  For instance, if your server starts stalling and responding slower, you're going to continue stacking commands that the server can't handle (which may cascade in other errors).

When working with AD I've seen the Domain Controller freak out when too many commands come in (similar to a DOS attack) and bring the server to a crawl or crash.  I think by using the sleep method you're creating a manageable and measurable flow.

In this instance, using a thread with a low priority *may* slow it down, but not to any controllable level.  The thread priority will only be a factor on the machine sending the commands, not to the server having to process them.

Hope this helps; cheers!

Comment: Never mind that there are other, better ways to do x number of things every y number of seconds.  Timers, for example, are a pretty easy way to do periodic tasks (like, say, sending a handful of commands) without blocking your UI and such.  A sleeping thread is a waste, and a sign you haven't thought something through.

Comment: Good catch, didn't think about a timer.  That would be a much better way of doing things.  I'll make some edits to add it.

Comment: @JamesBarnett I voted this up and then you completely changed your answer so I have removed my vote, sorry. I thought about a timer but I think sleep would be simpler.

Comment: @MikeKulls I still agree Thread.Sleep is the best way to go.  Just that the timer is another way to go about it; but I think you have less control (see the second paragraph).  Not begging for points, but I'm on here to learn as well - is there a reason that I'm missing?

Comment: @MikeKulls: `Thread.Sleep` does *look* simpler, if you can't let go of a synchronous mindset.  But it has issues.  (1) Waking up early is all but impossible without another thread's interference.  (2) It ties up a thread that could be doing something less useless than sitting around waiting.  If that thread happens to be your event handling thread, you're a bit screwed.  (3) It encourages a *process ALL THE THINGS!* mindset, guiding you toward writing a big slab of code for the whole job when it probably ought to be much more granular.  There are others.

Comment: @All Sorry if I'm biased, I'm an ASP.NET developer and we don't have access to doing asynchronous commands.  Not to defend that there's not a better way in my response, but it's something we don't always think about first.  ASP.NET 4.5 is the first version we're able use asynchronous operations (through Microsoft).

Comment: @James: Oi.  Even worse than sleeping, is sleeping *in a web app*.  :P  ASP.net doesn't even like generating a page til everything's done, does it?

Comment: @JamesBarnett It's more that what I voted for and what your answer now says are different. Previously you said Sleep was the best way to handle it which is what I voted for, now you say Sleep is one way to handle it. I also voted because of the last paragraph which sums up very well why i think thread priority is basically not a solution. I've restored the vote anyway because I think your answer is still accurate.

Comment: @James: Yeah.  A timer can start chunks up on another thread, freeing up the UI thread or HTTP handler.

Comment: @MikeKulls Thanks for the upvote, I'm curious if you have a better explanation than me about why .sleep is the better way to handle it. It's the way I know, and the way I know colleagues of mine haven't ever had an issue with. And cHao I'll see if I can't figure something out, I'm not afraid to be wrong and would like to know if something in the asp world allows for a better thought (besides calling some kind of service that updates me on the status).

Comment: Yeah could have done a timer. Use backgroundworker so the ui thread is free.

Answer (score 2):

The `Thread.Sleep()` method will just put the thread in a pause state for the specified amount of time. I could tell you there are 3 different ways to achieve the same `Sleep()` calling the method from three different Types. They all have different features. Anyway most important, if you use `Sleep()` on the main UI thread, it will stop processing messages during that pause and the GUI will look locked. You need to use a BackgroundWorker to run the job you need to sleep.

My opinion is to use the Thread.Sleep() method and just follow my previous advice. In your specific case I guess you'll have no issues. If you put some efforts looking for the same exact topic on SO, I'm sure you'll find much better explanations about what I just summarized before.

If you have no way to receive a feedback from the called service, like it would happen on a typical event driven system (talking in abstract..we could also say callback or any information to understand how the service is affected by your call), the Sleep may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is not overload the server you can just reduce the priority of the thread.

`Thread.Sleep()` do not consume any resources. However, the correct way to do this is set the priority of thread to a value below than Normal: `Thread.Current.Priority = ThreadPriority.Lowest` for example.

`Thread.Sleep` is not that "evil, do not do it ever", but maybe (just maybe) the fact that you need to use it reflects some lack on solution design. But this is not a rule at all.

Personally I never find a situation where I *have* to use Thread.Sleep. 
Right now I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application that uses a background thread to load a lot of data from database into a memory cache and after that write some data to the database. 
The only feature I have used to prevent this thread to eat all my webserver and db processors was reduce the thread priority to the Lowest level. That thread will get about to 35 minutes to conclude all the operations instead of 7 minutes if a use a Normal priority thread. By the end of process, thread will have done about 230k selects to the database server, but this do not has affected my database or webserver performance in a perceptive way for the user.

**tip:** remember to set the priority back to Normal if you are using a thread from ThreadPool.

Here you can read about Thread.Priority: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx

Here a good article about why not use Thread.Sleep in production environment:
http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2007/04/26/thread-sleep-is-a-sign-of-a-poorly-designed-program.aspx

**EDIT** Like others said here, maybe just reduce your thread priority will not prevent the thread to send a large number of commands/data to AD. Maybe you'll get better results if you rethink all the thing and use timers or something like that. I personally think that reduce priority could resolve your problem, although I think you need to do some tests using *your data* to see what happens to your server and other servers involved in the process.

Comment: Would this actually help though? It's likely most of the actual work is not being done by this thread as this thread just sends the request to add the user. It's also possible the code is not even running on the server itself.

Comment: @MikeKulls, I underdant your point, but we do not have the details of implementation to say "this" or "that" is better. What we can do is answer the question. Thread.Sleep() is not good after all.

Comment: Why do you say thread.Sleep is a bad idea? I think it is possible that it would solve the problem where setting the priority might have little effect.

Comment: @MikeKulls, do not use Thread.Sleep is a good practice, but I don't think that is evil too. I tried to respond the two questions that was made without considering the other parts, since we do not have the details. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MikeKulls, I made an update on my answer to explain why I suggested Thread.Priority instead of Thread.Sleep.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this but I think that changing the priority is basically a non workable solution. This solution should be able to be run from a separate machine and setting the priority is simply changing the priority on the workstation. If the workstation is otherwise idle then it's unlikely to slow down at all. If the workstation is busy then it's likely to stop altogether. Basically we want to control the load on the server but you are just controlling the load on the workstation. On the other hand setting a timer or sleep gives us what we want, limit the requests per second

Comment: @MikeKulls, maybe you're right because I think the thread priority solution will depend on the kind of data and processing being made. Better run some tests to see what happens, since it's to change the code and add an extra line. For me it works well, but for sure this solution do not work for every scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You could schedule the thread at `BelowNormal` [priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx) instead. That said, that could potentially lead to your task never running if something else overloads the server. (Assuming Windows scheduling works the way the [documentation on scheduling threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k34xtf3.aspx) mentions for "some operating systems".)

That said, you said you're moving data into AD. If it's over the nework, it's entirely possible the CPU impact of your code will be negligible compared to I/O and processing on the AD side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with it except that during the time you put the thread to sleep then that thread will not be responsive. If that is your main thread then your GUI will become non responsive. If it is a background thread then you won't be able to communicate with it (eg to cancel it). If the time you sleep is short then it shouldn't matter.

I don't think reducing the priority of the thread will help as 1) your code might not even be running on the server and 2) most of the work being done by the server is probably not going to be on your thread anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.sleep does not aid performance (unless your thread has to wait for some resource).  It incurs at least some overhead, and the amount of time that you sleep for is not guaranteed.  The OS can decide to have your Thread sleep longer than the amount of time you specify.

As such, it would make more sense to do a significant batch of work between calls to Thread.Sleep().

Answer (score 0):

Thread.Sleep() is a CPU-less wait state. Its overhead should be pretty minimal. If execute `Thread.Sleep(0)`, you don't [necessarily] sleep, but you voluntarily surrender your time slice so the scheduler can let lower priority thread run.

You can also lower your thread's priority by setting `Thread.Priority`.

Another way of throttling your task is to use a [`Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer):

```
// instantiate a timer that 'ticks' 10 times per second (your ideal rate might be different)
Timer timer = new Timer( ImportUserIntoActiveDirectory , null , 0 , 100 ) ;
```

where `ImportUserIntoActiveDirectory` is an event handler that will import just user into AD:

```
private void ImportUserIntoActiveDirectory( object state )
{
  // import just one user into AD
  return
}
```

This lets you dial things in. The event handler is called on thread pool worker threads, so you don't tie up your primary thread. Let the OS do the work for you: all you do is decide on your target transaction rate.